# C++ unordered_map hash function unable to find object

Tags: c++, object, find, unordered-map

I have a class Scheduler that contains an unordered_map of two objects.

```cpp
class Scheduler
{
public:
...

private:
    unordered_map<Time, Activity> schedule;

}
```

I get an error: 'list iterator not dereferenceable' - implying that the object was not found in here:

```cpp
void appoint(Time &time, const string activity) 
{
    Time hashTime(time + incrementor);
    schedule.find(hashTime)->second.active = 1; // <-- here
}
```

Here are my hash tools:

```cpp
namespace std {
    // does get here
    template <>
    struct hash<Time>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const Time& k) const
        {
            return ((hash<short>()(k.hr)
                ^ (hash<short>()(k.min) << 1)) >> 1)
                ^ (hash<bool>()(k.morning) << 1);
        }
    };
}


struct Time {
    short hr, min;
    bool morning;

    // doesnt get here
    bool operator==(const Time &other) const
    {
        return (hr == other.hr && min == other.min
                && morning == other.morning);
    }
}
```

Here is evidence for its existence in the unordered_map.

[image: unordered_map elements]

I've confirmed that `it == schedule.end()` is true.

```cpp
        auto it = schedule.find(hashTime);
        if (it == schedule.end()) {
            cout << "ok";
        }


        // this does manage to get found
        schedule.insert(make_pair(Time(9, 30, 1), Activity(0,"")));
        auto it2 = schedule.find(hashTime);
        if (it2 == schedule.end()) {
            cout << "ok";
        }
```

Somehow my initial construction of the map is incorrect.

```cpp
Scheduler() 
{
    Time start(12,0,1);             // 12:00am
    Time incrementor;               // 00:00
    Time static_incrementor(0, 15); // 00:15

    // creates an empty schedule
    // there are 96, 15 min intervals from 12:00am to 11:45pm
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
        Time newTime(start + incrementor);
        newTime.morning = true;
        cout << newTime.hr << ":" << newTime.min << newTime.morning << endl;

        schedule.insert(make_pair(newTime, Activity(0, "")));
        incrementor += static_incrementor;
    }

    Time start2(12, 0, 0); // 12:00pm
    Time incrementor2;     // 00:00
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
        Time newTime(start2 + incrementor2);
        newTime.morning = false;
        cout << newTime.hr << ":" << newTime.min << newTime.morning << endl;

        schedule.insert(make_pair(newTime, Activity(0, "")));
        incrementor2 += static_incrementor;
    }
};
```

Comment: What does your `operator ==()` look like for `Time`?  You need to [edit] your question to show us a [mcve].  In particular, note the **Minimal** (you need to reduce the problem to the smallest example program which shows the problem), and **Complete** (you need to include the whole program).

Comment: Sorry.  You do have the `operator ==()`.  Beg your pardon.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Our comments crossed in the post.

Comment: Blueman:  You have shown us that "9:30am" is in the hash map.  You haven't shown us that you are looking for "9:30am" when you get the error.

Comment: I've included a full pastebin link for `Time`.

Comment: @MartinBonner You can be reassured that the red text in the image is `hashTime`

Comment: That's not good enough.  We do *not* want the full code of `Time` - we want a minimal, cut-down, `Time` that shows the problem.  We also don't want a pastebin link (which will rot), we want the code in the question.

Comment: *Put an MCVE in your code.* Without it, the very best you can expect are complete wags (wild-ass-guesses). If I were debugging this, I would `auto it = schedule.find(...);`, verify `it != schedule.end()` before the dereference, and if it *did* equate to `schedule.end()`, stop on a breakpoint before gracefully aborting the request. Blindly dereferencing iterators from search results is a recipe for disaster

Comment: Ok. I've confirmed that it does reach schedule.end(). I'll get to work getting an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue - but do not completely understand it. Is this because each insertion now ensures a unique construction? Perhaps someone can comment.

```cpp
schedule.insert(make_pair(Time(newTime.hr, newTime.min, newTime.morning), 
                        Activity(0, "")));
```

Comment: I don't know whether it is the cause of your problem, but insert will place a copy of the pair in the unordered_map. Try using the emplace member function instead, assuming you are using c++11.